# Chef-client kills processes

Tags: amazon-ec2, knife, chef

I use the *knife ec2 plugin* to bootstrap a new instance (Ubuntu 12.04) and install a software on it. Everything works great but after chef-client ends, some processes of the new software are killed. The weird thing is that this only appears with bootstrapping. If I bootstrap first a new instance and run the recipes afterwards this problem does not appear. 
As Chef Server I use hosted chef.
Any ideas what the problem could be?

Answer (score 1):

Linux will kill processes if the system is in danger of running out of memory [0], perhaps this is happening? grep /var/log/syslog for the phrase "oom" (can't remember if it is in capitals or not) - this will tell you if processes are being killed due to lack of memory.

0: http://linuxdevcenter.com/pub/a/linux/2006/11/30/linux-out-of-memory.html

Answer (score 0):

Check dmesg for out of memory errors

```
dmesg | grep OOM
```

This can happen almost surely if this is a micro instance you're running. In this case, add a swap file recipe  before everything else (try this one: https://gist.github.com/4171136) and your issues will be over!